# How to force Linux to use a specific video card from two available gpu?

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, graphics

system and hardware:
MB: MSI Z170A PC MATE;
Intel i7-6700 3.4GHz;
Nvidia GTX 750 Ti; 
Nvidia GTX 960;
2 PCIe 3.0 x16 (1st slot) and x4 (2nd slot);
Noveau driver

**Goal: make the 2nd PCIe slot with its containing card the system default graphic card, with the card in the 1st PCIe slot being claimed by pci-stub**

tried so far:

- BIOS allows only a choice between Intel IG (iGPU) and "external" GPU (eGPU).
- If a card is in the first or second slot with BIOS switched to eGPU it will recognize it flawlessly and run it with Noveau.
- If I add then the 2nd card the system will alway choose the one in the PCIe x16 slot (1st slot).
- If I claim the 1st PCIe x16 card with pci-stub via kernel commandline and attach the 2nd card at the PCIe x4 slot then the screen attached to the 2nd card remains inactive while screen attached to the 1st will run but remain black without any output.
- the other way around with 2nd card claimed by stub everything works fine

Is there a way to force the system to choose the 2nd PCIe x4 slot by default? For example would it help to describe the 2nd card explicitely in a Xorg.conf file? Or is there a way to tell the kernel to use a specific card for video output? Or am I out of luck with my motherboard?

Comment: same problem here, but with vfio-pci (instead of pci-stub) and GA-AX370-Gaming-5 mobo ... except stranger... 3rd GPU is used by bios (strange) and if I force linux to use the 3rd card (by binding vfio-pci to the rest), then text ttys are gone (moved to 1st gpu?) but Xorg works on the 3rd (I manually set it in xorg.conf). And the iommu group that has most the usb ports and 1/2 sata controllers contains the 3rd card (annoying...the root cause of my problem). passthrough of the 2nd card works fine though.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the manual for xrandr -- man xrandr.

```
xrandr --listproviders
```

should list all your cards.  Laptops typically use two GPUs, the discrete (Nvidia) for the bulk of the work, and the Intel for  the writing to screen. In the provider list, the Nvidia will be named "NVIDIA-G0" and should be the source output, and the Intel will be named "modesetting" and should be the sink output.  Change them with the xrandr --setprovideroutputsource and --setprovideroffloadsink options.

Other environment variables may allow control of the source/sink e.g.:

```
 __NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia
```

I have noticed sometimes the CUDA samples on Ubuntu 22.04 don't run because the source/sink are reversed, and the above environment variables need to be set before the executable.